# How to define Length of of PLSQL procedure parameters?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I tried using the below code , but it didnt compile , is defining plsql procedure with parameter values having specific lengths possible in PLSQL.

```
create or replace procedure test_proc1(tid in number(2))
is
  begin
  null;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should'nt specify the size of number in procedure argument (idem for varchar2)